# How to get the creation date of a tag in BitBucket Server (aka Stash)

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Update May 2023: There is no way to achieve this from the API for Stash

Using **BitBucket Server (aka Stash) version 6.3.0** I am trying to filter tags of a repository according to a specific date range., but can't find the creation date of a tag.

From the [API Docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.3.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp319), using the `GET /REST/API/1.0/PROJECTS/{PROJECTKEY}/REPOS/{REPOSITORYSLUG}/TAGS` API we can order the results by modification date, but the tag object itself does not contain a created/updated field. This is not related to if the tag is annotated or not.

**Tag response:**

```json
{
    "size": 1,
    "limit": 25,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "release-2.0.0",
            "displayId": "refs/tags/release-2.0.0",
            "type": "TAG",
            "latestCommit": "8d351a10fb428c0c1239530256e21cf24f136e73",
            "latestChangeset": "8d351a10fb428c0c1239530256e21cf24f136e73",
            "hash": "8d51122def5632836d1cb1026e879069e10a1e13"
        }
    ],
    "start": 0
}
```

The only option I have found so far is to fetch the commit itself, but the date of the commit isn't necessarily the date of tag as I can create a tag at any stage regardless of the commit creation date.

Does anyone know of any workaround regarding this that I can use in order to get the creation date of a tag?